# Android, Kotlin: What exactly is called here?

Tags: android, kotlin

I had Android Studio convert my code for an `OnClickListener`.

Obviously a lambda is used here. What I don't know is whether the lambda is passed to a function of the View class or to the constructor of the `OnClickListener` class.

I have already looked in the Android documentation for a method with the name `OnClickListener` in the `View` class but found nothing.

If the latter is the case, I don't understand how an instance of the `OnClickListener` class can be created even though it is an interface.

```
val onClickListener = View.OnClickListener { refreshListView() }
```

Comment: It's called anonymous classes. They can be created on the fly without explicitly defining them in some file. Also, check SAM conversions.

Comment: [sam-conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions)

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski As far as I know, an anonymous object should be announced with "object".  In addition, an inheriting class from View.OnClickListener would have to override the OnClick () method, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class OnClickListener is an inner class of the View class:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener

Inner classes are identified by a '.' in their classname, on byte code level they are separated with a '$' instead.

With the invocation as written in your question you create an anonymous class implementing the functional interface and implementing its onClick(View) method. You can do the same in Java with a bit more verbose syntax, but technically the same.

Comment: I already know that.  What I don't understand is what is described above

Comment: First, as far as I know, an anonymous object must be announced in Kotlin with "object".  Second, the View.OnClickListener class is an interface, so I have to override the onClick () method if I inherit from it.

Comment: Its explained here: https://medium.com/tompee/idiomatic-kotlin-lambdas-and-sam-constructors-fe2075965bfb, SAM constructors.